# How to query all contents of a field

Tags: mysql, sql

So I've got a table named departments and it has a field named location, how can I select all records from the location field?

Comment: what is the point in asking questions that show a complete lack of effort on your part?

Comment: Not really..sorry if it looks dat way but I'm new to this..i knw the questions r simple but a little help is all I need.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/ is a good place to start looking for "little help".

Answer (score 0):

For *all* of them it's:

```
SELECT location
FROM departments
```

That will contain duplicates if they exist. To show each value only once regardless of how often it appears it's:

```
SELECT DISTINCT location
FROM departments
```